# Como eu faço para atualizar a tabela do HTML após de cadastrar os dados

Tags: php, html5, ajax

Este código já faz o cadastro em AJAX e filtra os dados da tabela do HTML, confira o código.

### HTML

Este é uma parte do código HTML, onde eu mostro os dados da tabela

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include_once 'sidebar.php'; ?>
        <?php include_once '../importante/table_header.php'; ?>
        <?php include_once '../importante/select_header.php'; ?>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Static Form -->
        <form method="post" action="../servidor/c_organizar_crianca.php" id="idForm">
        <!-- Tabela -->
        <table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="false" data-search="true" data-show-columns="true" data-show-pagination-switch="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-key-events="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-resizable="true" data-cookie="true"
            data-cookie-id-table="saveId" data-show-export="false" data-click-to-select="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th data-field="" data-checkbox="false"></th>
            <th data-field="id">ID</th>
            <th data-field="name" data-editable="false">NOME</th>
            <th data-field="idade" data-editable="false">IDADE</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php

            $query = "SELECT * FROM crianca ORDER BY id ASC";
            $ver = Crianca::findBySql(con(), $query);

            $query1 = "SELECT * FROM organizar_crianca ORDER BY id ASC";
            $view = OrganizarCrianca::findBySql(con(), $query1);
            //Faz o controle das crianças que já foram organizadas
            for($a = 0;$a<count($view);$a++){$total=$a;}
            $pega=0;$a=0;$id = 0;
            //id - conta o index do criança

            foreach ($ver as $i):
            $id++;$pega=0;$a=0;

            foreach ($view as $i1){
                if($i1->getCriancaId() == $i->getId()){$pega=1;}
              if($pega!=1 && $total == $a ){
            ?>       
            <tr>
                <td> <input type="checkbox" name="seleciona[]" value="<?php echo $i->getId() ?>" > </td>
                <td data-name="id"><?php echo $i->getId() ?></td>
                <td data-name="nome"><?php echo $i->getNome() ?></td>
                <td data-name="idade"><?php echo $i->getIdade() ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
             }$a++; }endforeach;
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <!--END Tabela -->
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

### PHP

ESTE É O PHP ONDE EU FAÇO O CADASTRO DOS DADOS

```
    <?php
     //Conecta com a base de dados
    include_once 'conectar.php';

    $educador = $_POST['s_educador'];
    $turma = $_POST['s_turma'];
    $sala = $_POST['s_sala'];

    //Verifica se foi selecionado um educador
    if(!empty($educador)){
        //Verifica se foi selecionado uma criança
        if(isset($_POST['seleciona'])){
            $selecionado = $_POST['seleciona'];
            //Pega o total das crianças selecionadas
            for($a = 0;$a<count($selecionado);$a++){$total=$a;}
            //Cadastra as crianças selecionadas
            for($i = 0;$i<count($selecionado);$i++){
                $selecionar = $selecionado[$i];

                $organizar = new OrganizarCrianca();
                $organizar->setFuncionarioId($educador);
                $organizar->setCriancaId($selecionar);
                $organizar->setTurmaId($turma);
                $organizar->setSalaId($sala);

                if(!$organizar->insertIntoDatabase(con())){
                    //Erro ao cadastro
                    returnAjax($r, '1');
                }else{
                    if($total == $i){
                        //Sucesso ao cadastro
                        returnAjax($r, '0');
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            //Por favor seleciona uma criança
            returnAjax($r, '2');
        }
    }else{
        //Por favor seleciona um educador
        returnAjax($r, '3');
    }
    ?>
```

### AJAX

E ESTE É O SCRIPT DO AJAX

```
    <script>
        function submeterOrganizar(idForm){

        //frm -> pega o id do formulário, para ter o acesso a todos os conteúdo do formulario (metodo,acção...).
        let frm = $('#'+idForm);
        
        //Quando o formulário for submetido será executado automaticamente
        frm.submit(function(e){
            //e -> é usado para impedir que o formulário será submetido de forma normal.
            //preventDefault() -> impedi a submetido tradicional.
            e.preventDefault();
            
            //Evitando que barbarizão o formulário de cadastro
                if($("#enviar").val() === "Enviando..."){
                    return false;
                }
                $("#enviar").val("Enviando...");
            
            $.ajax({
                dataType:'json',
                type: frm.attr('method'),
                url: frm.attr('action'),
                data: frm.serialize(),
                cache: false,
                //Verificações
                beforeSend: function(){
                   progresso();
                },
                success: function(i){
                    if(i.numero === '0'){
                        $("#enviar").val("...");
                        
                        //sucesso do cadastro
                        //sucesso();
                        alert("sucesso do cadastro");
                        vazio();
                    }else if(i.numero === '1'){
                        //erro();
                        $("#enviar").val("...");
                         alert("Erro do cadastro");
                        vazio();
                    }else if(i.numero === '2'){
                        //erro_espaco();
                        $("#enviar").val("...");
                         alert("Por favor seleciona uma criança");
                        vazio();
                    }else if(i.numero === '3'){
                        //erro ao cadastrar
                        $("#enviar").val("...");
                         alert("Por favor seleciona um educador");
                         vazio();
                    }
                },
                //erro do Ajax
                error: function(){
                    //alert("Numero = "+i.numero);
                    alert("Surgiu um erro...");
                    //vazio();
                }
            });
        });
    }
    /*------------------------------- Area do alert ------------------------------------------*/
    //Mostra o alerta sucesso
    /*
    function sucesso(){document.getElementById("basicSuccessAnimation").click();}
        //Mostra o alerta erro
    function erro(){document.getElementById("basicErrorAnimation_usuario").click();}
    function erro_espaco(){document.getElementById("basicErrorAnimation_usuario_espaco").click();}
    */
    //Progresso
    function progresso(){document.getElementById("progresso").src="../../img/progresso/loading1.gif";}
    function vazio(){document.getElementById("progresso").src="";}
</script>
```

Comment: Você já tentou no retorno do ajax, pegar os dados enviados e criar uma nova linha na tabela usando jquery append?

Comment: Já, deu certo valeu pela ajuda.